# Проверка четности числа в C++

Tags: c++, числа, проверка

Забыл, как проверить число на чётность в `C++`. В коде надо проверить, является число чётным или нет.

Comment: У четных чисел остаток от деления на 2 равен 0. Оператор вычиcления остатка `%`.

Answer (score 1):

Для этого можно просто использовать `if` и деление с остатком (`%`):

```
size_t number = 123;
if (number % 2 == 0)
{
    cout << "true" << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "false" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В дополнение к ответу Bloody.cpp. Т.к. у нечетных чисел младший бит всегда равен 1, а у четных нулю - то такая проверка тоже имеет место быть и даже чуть быстрее работает.

```
bool isEven(int n)
{
    return !(n&1);
}
```